# How is the thread model implemented in Karaf?

Tags: multithreading, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

i am trying to understand the karaf thread model.
from what i can understand in OSGI in case the bundle starts threads it is also responsible for closing them.
is this the case in karaf as well?
are there any other solutions for managing threads in karaf?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: i have a bundle, as part of its logic a number of threads are created. now i want to understand what will happen to the threads if i shut down the bundle that created them. will they be terminated by the osgi container or do i need to manually stop them on shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the extra comment.
No the OSGi framework will not manage your threads. 
If you spawn threads from your bundle, you are supposed to take care of it. 
For example in the stop Method of your Activator you can stop the thread pool you used.

Answer (score 0):

Threads in OSGi work like in plain Java. So for example you can use Executors.